# Toddler aggressively pulling at genitals leaving scratches and red marks

Tags: toddler

I understand it is common for children of this age to explore but my son the moment he is diaper free will grab his genitals and pull on his scrotum so hard and several times to the points he has either scratched himself or it’s all red and irritated. He gets changed regularly, is showing no signs of a reaction to diapers or wipes, and this is a new behavior. It’s constant. Not just every once in a while. To the point I have to immediately keep his hands away while changing him.

Comment: Hi and welcome! What is your actual question? Is it to ask if this is normal, to ask how to prevent it, or something else? This is a Q&A site, and we need an actual question, or we'll just be guessing at an answer. Please edit to clarify. Thanks.